# how to get starting position of every connected component of an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using **"bwconncomp"** method to get connected component of this image.  [image]
There are four **connected components bounded by red boxes** and **every starting point** of every connected component is **marked by a yellow point**.The co-ordinate of that **yellow point is (x , y)** **which is only for the first component from left**. At the first connected component(which is now a separate image) from the left side , you see a **blue point which is the gravity center of that particular connected component**. I can easily calculate that **blue point co-ordinate as (x1 , y1)**. If i want to calculate the position of that gravity center with respect to the whole image then the co-ordinate will be **(x+x1 , y+y1)**. My question is how can i get the (x , y) co-ordinate in matlab?**Fully functional code will be more helpful as i am not an expert in matlab.

Main image is here [image]

Comment: Can you add another image without the box, i.e the same image but only with that black text so that it would be easy for those, to take the same image and solve your problem??

Comment: I have added it @ Santhan Salai

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the best things about matlab is the [`regionprops`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html?refresh=true) function. It allows you to hand it an image (black and white, connected component, or labelled image) and it will return a `stats` object which contains loads of information about each connected component in the image.

You can limit the information returned (and therefore calculated, which can save time) by telling it which property you want. To get the bounding box (which it sounds like you want) you would say

```
stats = regionprops(Image,'boundingbox');
```

Then, `stats.BoundingBox` contains an array with the `[x_position y_position width height]`.

Hope that points you in the right direction, and experiment with `regionprops(Image,'all')` to see all of the information you can get from an image.

Comment: sorry , couldn't do it. i have been only able to do this `con_comp = bwconncomp(binary_image,8);
number_of_object = con_comp.NumObjects;
stats = regionprops(con_comp,'boundingbox');
[ul_corner, width] = stats.BoundingBox; `, i am not good in matlab so what i need is fully functional code @cwissy

Comment: if you look at the `stats` object, it will be a stuct of structs. It contains what you want - the xy coordinates of the bounding box. So you could do `boxes = cat(1, stats.BoundingBox);` and boxes will be a matrix, the first 2 columns of which are your xy coordinates for your points

Comment: what about 3rd and 4th column? @cwissy

Comment: the 3rd and 4th columns are width and height. If this has answered your question, you can accept it by the way. And you can find more information on regionprops here: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html